# Mapbox for Android, using Tiles from a server

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox-android

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to use Mapbox on Android with tiles stored in a server.

I know the tiles are available because I can make them appear on the web.
I can use the default styles no problem `mapBox.setStyle(Style.LIGHT)` but when I try to change the map style using the server tiles.

I'm creating a `JsonObject`:

```
val mapJSONObject = JsonObject()
```

which is the equivalent of this:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "tiles-name": {
    "type": "raster",
    "url": "https://myserver.com/map/c16c1u38213f0db8001b1c6e8cee5f7a/{z}/{x}/{y}?token=jfsdajfdsjkfjksh34232fsd",
    "tileSize": 256
    }
  },
  "layers": [{
    "id": "ee-raster",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": "tiles-name",
    "minzoom": 0,
    "maxzoom": 22
  }]
}
```

I've tried to use this `JsonObject` by either calling it by:

```
map.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromJson(mapJSONObject.toString()))
```

or by creating a .json file via this function:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun save(context: Context, jsonString: String) {
    val rootFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
    val jsonFile = File(rootFolder, "file.json")
    val writer = FileWriter(jsonFile)
    writer.write(jsonString)
    writer.close()
}
```

then using that .json file via:

```
map.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromJson("file.json"))
```

When triggering the change map using:

```
map.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromJson(mapJSONObject.toString()))
```

I get the error message:

> D/Mbgl-HttpRequest: [HTTP] Request with response = 404: No additional
>   information 
>   [Style]: Failed to load source tiles-name: HTTP status code 404

When triggering the change map using:

```
map.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromJson("file.json"))
```

I get the error message:

> [ParseStyle]: Failed to parse style: Invalid value. at offset 1

I have trouble debugging this, even though the error messages seem clear enough.

I have been reading through the MapBox documentation, but can't seem to find a clear example using tiles from tiles on a server.

Can anyone identify what might be the issue or point me to an example using this method?

Doesn't have to be in Kotlin, Java would be equally useful.